Strange substitution made in a paper to find asymptotics
In the quoted section from this paper, why is the author able to "substitute this result into Eq. (2.1)"? This should hold for $z$ large. But not everything on the contour is large. Why can the author make this substitution?

Let $T=\frac{4}{27} t^3$ and  $K_{1 / 6}(T)$ be the modified Bessel functions of order $\frac{1}{6}$. Now previously the paper showed
$$\operatorname{Ai}^3(x)=C_1 \int_{\mathcal{L}_1} t^{1 / 2} K_{1 / 6}(T) \exp \left(\frac{5}{27} t^3-x t\right) d t \qquad \qquad (2.1)
$$
(If you see a rectangle, the symbol is mathcal{L}_1). Next we need to show that the constant $C_1$ can be chosen so that both sides of this equation have the same asymptotic behavior as $x \rightarrow \infty$. For that purpose we first recall that in the complete sense of Watson [3]
$$
K_{1 / 6}(T) \sim\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{3 / 2} \pi^{1 / 2} t^{-3 / 2} e^{-T} \quad\left(|\operatorname{ph} t|<\frac{1}{3} \pi\right)
$$
Substituting this result into Eq. (2.1) Why? then gives
$$
\operatorname{Ai}^3(x) \sim C_1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{3 / 2} \pi^{1 / 2} \int_{\mathcal{L}_1} t^{-1} \exp \left(\frac{1}{27} t^3-x t\right) d t
$$
and an application of the saddle-point method to this integral gives
$$
\operatorname{Ai}^3(x) \sim i C_1 2^{3 / 2} 3 \pi x^{-3 / 4} e^{-3 \xi}
$$



Even before that question: is $T$ in equation (2.1) supposed to be $t$? What caused the exponential term in the integral to go from $\frac5{27}t^3$ to $\frac1{27}t^3$?

@GregMartin The reason is because we get an $e^{-T}=e^{-\frac{4}{27}t^3}$ from the asymptotics then when plugged into 2.1 we get $e^{\frac{5}{27}t^3 - \frac{4}{27}t^3}=e^{\frac{1}{27}t^3}$
